# What are valid node types for the Range setEndAfter function in Safari?

Tags: javascript, dom

I am writing a module that should allow users to select parts of an HTML document. To get the internals to work I expand the `Range` of the selection to a valid HTML snippet.

For the case where B is a descendant of A I find the ancestor of B which is a child of A and want to set the range to end after that node using setEndAfter. This is what I have now:

```
var closestChild = function (node, descendant) {
    var parent;
    if (descendant.parentElement) {
        parent = descendant.parentElement;
        if ( node === parent ) {
            return descendant;
        }
        return closestChild(node, parent);
    }
    return false;
}

var legalRange = function (range) {
        var newRange = range.cloneRange(),
            child;
        if (range.startContainer === range.endContainer) {
            return newRange;
        }
        child = closestChild(range.startContainer.parentElement, range.endContainer.parentElement);
        if (child) {
            newRange.setEndAfter(child);
            return newRange;
        } 
        return null;
};
```

But this throws a  `INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: DOM Range Exception 2` when I try to set the end point. I have also tried using parentNode instead of parentElement with the same exception thrown. This is not a problem if i use setEnd(). What types of nodes should I pass to do this.

PS: It turns out that the code works in FireFox, so my problem is now with Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.
When I set up my test cases, I didn't add the elements to the document. It seems that Chrome and Safari treated the nodes as invalid when using setEndAfter if the nodes were not part of the document.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Eivind, the problem is that the node used to set the range position is not attached to the document. So one solution is to attach it before you set the range position.

Another solution, if you can't attach the node to the DOM for some reason, is to use `setStart()` and `setEnd()` instead.

```
// Instead of `range.setStartBefore(node)`
var parent = node.parent;
range.setStart(parent, Array.from(parent.childNodes).indexOf(node))

// Instead of `range.setStartAfter(node)`
var parent = node.parent;
range.setStart(parent, Array.from(parent.childNodes).indexOf(node) + 1)

// Instead of `range.setEndBefore(node)`
var parent = node.parent;
range.setEnd(parent, Array.from(parent.childNodes).indexOf(node))

// Instead of `range.setEndAfter(node)`
var parent = node.parent;
range.setEnd(parent, Array.from(parent.childNodes).indexOf(node) + 1)
```

Note: `Array.from(arrayLike)` is not supported in Internet Explorer <= 11. Use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike)` instead of you need IE support.